# Why isn't my brackets previewer not working?

Tags: text-editor, adobe-brackets

I've been using Notepad++ but decided to install Brackets. However, when I try to open my document to preview it live, I get an error saying "Open an HTML file or make sure there is an index.html file in your project in order to launch live preview". I dont understand why its not working when I set the name of my html document to "index" and have the "getting started" files they gave me as well. Can someone please help? Ive uploaded two screenshots to Imgur to show whats its saying:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/03hEq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First check to ensure you have a default browser set on your computer. After that, try duplicating your code into another folder, import that into adobe brackets, and than attempt to live preview it. If all else fails delete all traces of adobe brackets and reinstall it (you can save any programs you made, and import those back in later).

If problems persist post a bug on the offical [brackets trello](https://trello.com/b/LCDud1Nd/brackets) to get assistance by a developer.

Although, personally I reccommend just going into the folder directory, and selecting the .html file like you would if you were still using Notepad++. Everytime just save in brackets, and refresh in your browser. In my opinion, live preview doesn't offer that many beneficial features, the best just being recently added in version 1.9 (able to click a html element and jump to that code).